# SystemVerilog: Passing interfaces to functions/tasks (for synthesis!)

Tags: interface, system-verilog, synthesis

Is there any synthesizable way to pass an interface to a function or a task? My use case is the following: I have a package with several functions (though I could convert them to tasks, if that helps :) ), all of which might be used in a module and might need to access the ports of the module. Now, usually I'd just group all ports in an `interface`, add it to the module, and pass the it as `virtual` to the function. However, the manual of my synthesis tool mentions that `virtual` is not supported.

Am I missing anything? There must be a way to provide ports to tasks for synthesis, similar to VHDL's `signal` arguments?

Some example code:

```
module mymod (
    input logic clk,
    input logic rst,
    input uint16_t adr,
    input bit cyc,
    input uint32_t dat_m,
    input bit stb,
    input bit we,
    output bit ack,
    output uint32_t dat_s
    );

    always_comb begin
        mypack::do_something(a, b, c, adr, cyc, dat_m, stb, we, ack, dat_s);
endmodule
```

Ideally, the task `mypack::do_something` would be able to use the ports as ports, i.e. wait for changes on them, write values to them, etc; basically, the same you'd achieve in VHDL by passing them as `signal` arguments (as opposed to `variable` or `constant` arguments).

Answer (score 2):

Normally you'd declare any interface-specific functions in the interface definition itself. That way any task or function declarations already have the interface ports in scope.

```
interface int1(ports...);
  function func1(args...);
  // Do stuff with ports and args
  endfunction
endinterface

module mod1(input wire clk,interface intf);
...
  always @(posedge clk)
    intf.func1(module_specific_data); 
...
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. However, in my case the function implements module-specific behavior that just happens to use some of the module's ports. This rather strange indirection is due to the fact that the code is automatically generated and uses functions/packages for reasons outside of this question ;).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it looks like a interface must be virtual to be passed though a functions or tasks port list.

The SystemVerilog IEEE Std 1800-2009 says a function port list must be a data_type. See Section 13.4, Annex A.2.6, and Syntax 13-2 for the syntax of declaring a function. And see A.2.2.1 for defining a data_type. I checked the IEEE Std 1800-2005 too and it also seems to have the same restriction, just not spelled out clearly. See Section 12.3 and Annex A of 1800-2005.

If you want to use an interface, try using a translation function in the interface to make a struct (may require `packed`, see IEEE Std 1800-2009 Section 13.4, footnote#12):

```
interface myif ( /* ... */);
/* signal list */
function mypack::var_list_s toStruct();
   /* make translation */
endfunction : toStruct
endinterface : myif

module mymod(myif my_if);
always_comb
   mypack::do_something(my_if.toStruct(), my_if.ack, my_if.dat_s);
endmodule : mymod
```

Alternatively you can always do the classic `` `include "myports" `` where ever needed method.